# Bada Development

Tags: bada

How do I get started with development for the bada OS used in Samsung Wave?

What are the pre-requisites for this task? (I only know some C & C++)

Comment: Here's a good place to start: http://developer.bada.com/apis/index.do

Answer (score 1):

If you know C++ and you know about classes and classes inheritances you meet the pre-requisites  for strting bada development. It's not very hard. The API documentation is very well organized and you shouldn't have any problems finding out what you need. Even if you do have problems, there are resources on the internet where you can find help.

[BadaDev.com](http://badadev.com) and [BadaDev.com Community](http://forums.badadev.com/) are very useful resources for a beginner.

On BadaDev.com you will find a lot of tutorials most of them will answer a lot of day to day bada development question. And BadaDev.com Community is a very active forums where you could post your questions if you need help. People over there are nice and responsive.

Answer (score 0):

here's another link that you may find useful: http://www.drstrangecode.org/series/bada-from-scratch/

It's a tutorial series that I'm writing on my website about Bada Development, it starts from the very beginning by showing you how to install & setup a development environment, then it goes much deeper into Bada development.